# How to make "child" div DON'T overflow by itself and uses it's parent div's padding to render?

Tags: html, css

First, my codes

HTML:

```
<div class="div parent">
  Title
  <div class="div child">
    <div class="overflowed">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.overflowed {
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

Sorry I am not good at describe things about webpage designing, so if I describe something incorrectly, please tell me, thanks :)

How to make child div render like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9STQ.png), and it's bottom border always have margin to it's parent's bottom border?

By the way, "Title" in HTML line 2 will change it's height by different screen resolution, so it can't be limited by max-height property.

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dj3ydshf/

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there. I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
.div {
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .parent {
      max-height: 200px;
    }
    
    /* set overflow y-scroll */
    /* and give this element a max-height or height */
    .child {
      overflow: y-scroll;
      max-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div parent">
  tuitit

  <div class="limit">


    <div class="div child">
      SSSS
      <br> SSSS
      <br> SSSS
      <br> SSSS
      <br> SSSS
      <br> SSSS
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```